# Angular 2+ http get() JSON-data. Cannot .filter data

Tags: json, angular, http, dictionary, filter

I have a service.ts, where I use the get() method (http) to get data from a local JSON-file. It Works fine.

```
getMusic() {
  return this.http.get('assets/music.json')
.map((res:Response) => res.json())
```

In my class I have my 'suscribe':

```
ngOnInit() {this.musicService.getMusic().subscribe(
data => { this.music = data.music}
  );
}
```

My JSON-file looks like this:

```
{
"music" : [
    { 
        "no": 11, 
        "name": "Music 1",
    },   ...... aso....
```

Everything is perfect. Well now I'm trying to filter my data, so it only shows music with no=11.

I have this Imports:

```
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

I have tried several things. Including filtering for a number instead of a string, using == instead of ===, putting .filter inside or outsite .map aso. When I try this I receive no result at all. I get no errors, just no result:

```
getMusic() {
    return this.http.get('assets/music.json')
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .map(x => x.filter(y => y.name === 'Music 1'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong `filter` operator function. It should be filtering on `music`.

```
getMusic() {
    return this.http.get('assets/music.json')
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    //filter on `music` object instead of `x` directly
    .map(x => x.music.filter(y => y.name === 'Music 1'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `filter` function is applied to an array not to an instance of it
try using

```
this.filteredArr = this.music.filter(x=>x.name == 'music 1'); //some condition
```